# How to think about blank symbol when Turing Machine used as a function?

Tags: turing-machines, computability

Turing Machines can be used to compute functions.

For example `f(x)=x-1`.

`0011` is on the tape. Turing Machine computes for some time and finishes in accept state. On the tape, we see: `_00_10_`. Where `_` is a blank symbol. Is it correct? Meaning `0011 == _00_10_`.

For exaple in Python: `[] + [1] + [] + [2] + [] == [1,2]` is True.

When Turing Machine is used for recognizing language everything is clear. It is not important what is on the tape. Only final state: accept or reject.

Comment: You might want to check this: [Why is the blank symbol not considered part of the input alphabet of a turing machine](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/108983/why-is-the-blank-symbol-not-considered-part-of-the-input-alphabet-of-a-turing-ma)

Comment: As I understand the blank is used to detect the end of its input. It does not tell how to use it when Turing Machine is used as a function.

Comment: In your example you are using the blank symbol as part of your input to a TM, which the link I provided, would show that this should not be the case. If you need to use the blank as a delimiter or to represent an empty collection or null, then the way to go is not to use the blank tape symbol but instead use some encoding based solely on the available input symbols.

Comment: The blank symbol is not a part of my input. Input is `0011` and output is `_00_10_`